# Algorithm for rounding a corner between line and arc

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, automatic-ref-counting, rounded-corners

I need an algorithm that can round a corner between a line and an arc. The start information that I have is P0-start point, P-corner point, P2-end point, R2-radius of the arc between P and P2 and R-radius of the rounded corner(on the second picture).

[image: Corner between line and arc]

Output or wanted points are cross sections C0 and C2 and center point of the rounding circle-O

[image: Rounded corner between line and arc]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [efficient algorithm for drawing circle arcs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044444/efficient-algorithm-for-drawing-circle-arcs)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my sketch BF is part of given segment (F is not known yet), C is center of given arc, B is point of rough conjugation. `c` is line, parallel to BF, `|GF|=|GH| = r` - radius of small arc.

To make smooth conjugation, tangent to small arc in point F should be collinear with BF direction, so GF is perpendicular to BF, and tangents to both arcs in point H should coincide - so radius-vectors CH and GH lie on the same line. 
[image]

Let unit direction vector of BF segment is `ud=(dx,dy)`, so unit normal is `un=(-dy, dx)`. (Negate normal for arcs at another side of BF)

Center of small arc G has coordinates (where t is unknown parameter - length of BF)

```
G = B + ud * t + un * r
```

and distance GC is difference of arcs radii, so

```
 |G - C| = |R - r| 
   or in coordinates:
(B.x + dx * t - dy * r - C.x)^2 + (B.y + dy * t + dx * r - C.y)^2 = (R - r)^2
```

Open parentheses, solve quadratic equation for unknown t. If solutions exist, choose right root, and you'll get coordinates of center of conjugation arc G and its ends

quick check1:
Line Y=5, big arc with R=5, we want small arc with r=2

```
 B=(5,5)
 ud=(-1,0)
 un=(0,-1)
 (5-t)^2 + (5-2-5)^2 = (5-2)^2
 solution gives 
 t = 5 +/- Sqrt(5), the second root is valid
 E = (5 - (5 - Sqrt(5)), 3) = (2.23, 3)
```

Resulting smooth arc is `c-f`

[image]

quick check2:
Line Y=5, big arc with R=5, we want small arc with r=2

```
 B=(5,5)
 big arc center (H here) = (1,2)  
 ud=(-1,0)
 un=(0,-1)
 (4-t)^2 + (5-2-2)^2 = (5-2)^2
 solution gives 
 t = 4 +/- Sqrt(8), the second root is valid
 E = (5 - (4 - Sqrt(8)), 3) = (3.83, 3)
```

Resulting smooth arc is `F-G`

(In both cases larger root corresponds to conjugation with complementary part of big arc)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine but I have a few questions. How do you determine which root is valid? And how to solve for the small circle center if the roots are complex numbers?

Comment: I think that for "good" configurations valid root is smaller positive one (but I did not consider all possible configurations). If roots are complex  - then there is no solution with chosen approach for C1-continuity and given small radius)

Comment: Maybe I calculated the directional unit vector wrongly so that's why I get complex roots. These are the equations I used to calculate 
dx = (A.X - B.X) / Math.Abs(A.X - B.X) and 
dy = (A.Y - B.Y) / Math.Abs(A.Y - B.Y)

Comment: Yes, mistake. `Len = Sqrt((A.X - B.X)^2 + (A.Y - B.Y)^2); dx = (A.X - B.X) / Len, dy = (A.Y - B.Y) /Len` (for Len use routine Math.Hypot if available. or vectors supporting routines (Normalize etc))

Comment: Can this solution be implemented for rounding a corner between two arcs instead of line and arc

Comment: Equations will differ. Perhaps: find point Cr for  |Cr - C1| = |R1 - r|,  |Cr - C2| = |R2 - r| (like finding the third triangle vertex for two known verices and known edges)

Comment: Unit vectors ud and un stay the same ?

Comment: There no such vectors in case of two arcs. System of two quadratic equations for small arc center coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough specification to choose a unique arc.  You need to figure out what endpoints you want.  Then solve for the ellipse that is tangent to both of those points.  See [Wikipedia/ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) for the equations.  I recommend a math package (e.g. SciKit) to solve for you.