# Printing text in form of circle

Tags: python

I'm trying to form figures of the text a person chooses. 
I already made a square, pyramid and a parallelogram.

Where I get stuck is when I'm trying to make a circle. My thought was to use a `for i in range (1, height/2)` where it would print the text (f.e. --) * i times. Then I wanted another for loop to print the exact opposite, so from `height/2` to `height`, it should first print `height/2*` text en for every time the for loop starts again, it should print the text one time less.

I'm not completely sure if this will look like a circle somehow. 
I'll give my code for a pyramid and a circle. I'm aware that for the circle, I still need to do something with `" "`, but as I don't really know how to get everything working in the first place, I haven't began thinking about how I'm gonna need blank spaces in that code.

```
def print_pyramid(height):
    text = raw_input("Please give in what your pyramid needs to be formed from, you can choose two **, two --, or two letters")
    for i in range(1,height+1):
         print (height-i+1)*" ", text * i

def print_circle(height):
    text = raw_input("Give in what your circle is made of: **, -- or two letters.")
    for i in range(1,height/2):
        print text*i
    for j in range ((height/2)-1,(height/2)+1):
        print text*j
    for h in range((height/2)+2, height+1):
        print text*((height/2)-h)
```

[Example of output, see link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQIF8.jpg)

Comment: Can you share an example of your ideal output?

Comment: I'm assuming the current indentation is simply due to pasting. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33171682/edit) your question and properly indent your code.

Comment: See this related question: [fast algorithm for drawing filled circles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201200/fast-algorithm-for-drawing-filled-circles)

Comment: Edited my post to fix the identation and also to post an example of an output. I'm sorry if my code/questions aren't understandable, that's probably because I'm still very new at programming. Looked at that related question but I'm having a hard time to understand what's said there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that prints a circle of a given radius, using a single character. It uses Pythagoras' theorem to calculate the half-width of the circle at the current height, and multiplies that by the `xscale` constant to convert that to the full-width, with a scaling factor to take account of the fact that text cells on my screen are more than twice as tall as they are wide; you may need to adjust it a little for your screen.

It uses the `str.center` method to simplify positioning each row. In this demo, I start printing at radius = 4, because the smaller ones look terrible. :)

```
def text_circle(rad, ch='*'):
    xscale = 4.2

    #Maximum diameter, plus a little padding
    width = 3 + int(0.5 + xscale * rad)

    rad2 = rad ** 2
    for y in range(-rad, rad + 1):
        #Find width at this height
        x = int(0.5 + xscale * (rad2 - y ** 2) ** 0.5)
        s = ch * x
        print s.center(width)

for i in range(4, 15):
    print i
    text_circle(i, '@')
```

**output**

```
4

    @@@@@@@@@@@     
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
    @@@@@@@@@@@     

5

     @@@@@@@@@@@@@      
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@      

6

       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@       

7

        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@         
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@         

8

           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          

9

            @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@            
         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        
            @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@            

10

              @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@             
          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          
              @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@             

11

               @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@               
           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@           
         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        
           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@           
               @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@               

12

                 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                
             @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@            
          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          
             @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@            
                 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                

13

                  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                   
              @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@               
           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@            
         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        
         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          
           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@            
              @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@               
                  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                   

14

                    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                    
                @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                
             @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@             
          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@           
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@         
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      
       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@         
          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@           
             @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@             
                @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                
                    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Answer (score 5):

The area of a circle is *A = π r²*, so you can get the radius from the number of characters filling the circle<sup>1)</sup>. The equation of a circle of radius *r* is *x² + y² = r²*. You can use this to derive (half of) the width of a given line as *x = √(r² - y²)*. Then, just use a loop to iterate twice the radius and use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to print the next few characters from the text centred on the line.

```
from math import pi, sqrt, ceil
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."""
radius = ceil(sqrt(len(text)/pi))
text_iter = iter(text)

for i in range(-radius, radius+1):
    num = ceil(sqrt(radius**2 - i**2))
    print("{:^{}}".format("".join(next(text_iter, ".") for _ in range(2*num)), 2*radius))
```

Output:

```
       Lorem ipsu       
     m dolor sit am     
    et, consectetur     
   adipiscing elit, s   
  ed do eiusmod tempor  
  incididunt ut labore  
 et dolore magna aliqua 
. Ut enim ad minim venia
m, quis nostrud exercita
tion ullamco laboris nis
i ut aliquip ex ea commo
do consequat. Duis aute 
irure dolor in reprehend
erit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fu
giat nulla pariatur. Exc
 epteur sint occaecat c 
 upidatat non proident, 
   sunt in culpa qui o  
   fficia deserunt mo   
    llit anim id est    
      laborum......     
       ..........
```

Note how the text had to be padded as the radius has to be integer (thus `ceil`). Of course, you can do the same for printing just `.` (or any other placeholder), by setting `text = ""`

---

<sup>1)</sup> That is assuming each character is as wide as it is high, which is not really the case. I guess you can tweak the formula a bit to draw fewer lines with more characters per line instead.
For instance, you get a circle that appears (!) much rounder on screen (but really is oblated) by making the lines twice as wide.:

```
radius = ceil(sqrt(len(text)/(2*pi))) # calculate with 2 characters per "cell"
for i in range(-radius, radius+1):
    num = ceil(sqrt(radius**2 - i**2) * 2)
    print("{:^{}}".format("".join(next(text_iter, ".") for _ in range(2*num)), 4*radius))
```

Output:

```
         Lorem ipsum dolor          
      sit amet, consectetur ad      
    ipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo    
   d tempor incididunt ut labore    
 et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
  minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci 
tation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliqu
ip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aut
e irure dolor in reprehenderit in vo
luptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sin
 t occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
  sunt in culpa qui officia deserun 
   t mollit anim id est laborum..   
    ............................    
      ........................      
         ..................
```

Comment: Why are you not squaring x in your formula?  Shouldn't this be `ceil(sqrt(radius**2 - i**2))`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @saulspatz You are absolutely right, I missed that. Much simpler now. Thanks.