# Upside Down Pyramid (PY)

Tags: python

So I have an assignment that requires me to print an upside down pyramid made out of asterisks in Python. I know how to print out a normal pyramid but how do I flip it?
The height of the pyramid is determined by the input of the user. This is what I have for the normal pyramid:

```
#prompting user for input
p = int(input("Enter the height of the pyramid: "))


#starting multiple loops
for i in range(1,p+1): 
  for j in range(p-i):
    #prints the spacing
     print(" ",end='')
  #does the spacing on the left side
  for j in range(1,i):
    print("*",end='')
  for y in range(i,0,-1):
    print("*",end='')

  #does the spacing on the right side
  for x in range(p-i):
    print(" ",end='')



  #prints each line of stars
  print("")
```

Output:

```
Enter the height of the pyramid: 10
         *         
        ***        
       *****       
      *******      
     *********     
    ***********    
   *************   
  ***************  
 ***************** 
*******************
```

Comment: I have Python 3 if that means anything

Comment: Just change the outermost loop `for i in reversed(range(1,p+1)):` As simple as that.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks I'm new to Python

Comment: Seems we can start a library of code to print all those shapes of asterisks used as beginner's exercise: [Pyramid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179423/upside-down-pyramid-py), [M](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394149/draw-an-m-shaped-pattern-with-nested-loops), [Triangels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352412/python-print-a-triangular-pattern-of-asterisks), [Diamond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364162/print-shape-in-python), [Hollow square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108446/drawing-a-hollow-asterisk-square)

Comment: @cfi I bet that would be a bestseller! But don't forget to include [circles](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33171682/1639625)!

Comment: @tobias_k: Actually, I briefly searched for the circle but couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse the pyramid, just reverse the outer loop. Thanks to [the magic of python](http://xkcd.com/353/), you can just use the [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) builtin function.
Also, you can simplify the body of the loop a little bit using string multiplication and the [`str.center`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) function.

```
for i in reversed(range(p)):
    print(('*' * (1+2*i)).center(1+2*p))
```